# Can not replace the result of the method. Mockito

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito

There is a class called SessionManagerTest. In it, I do the mock, as it should, and I try to replace the result of the getCurrentSession method.

```
private SessionManager sessionManager;
@Before
public void init () {
    sessionManager = Mockito.mock (SessionManager.class);
    Mockito.when (sessionManager.getCurrentSession (any(), anyInt())). ThenReturn (new MyClassSession (1, 20171111, "cash_user"));
}
```

the method itself, from the SessionManager class

```
public MyClassSessionI getCurrentSession (BridgeConfigI bridgeConfig, Integer sessionDay) throws MyException {
    MyClassSessionI myClassSession = getSessionFromCache (bridgeConfig.getMandatoryParam ("user"), sessionDay);
    if (Optional.ofNullable (myClassSession) .isPresent ()) {
        sessionValidator.check (myClassSession);
        return myClassSession;
    }
    myClassSession = getSessionFromDatabase (bridgeConfig, sessionDay);
    if (Optional.ofNullable (myClassSession) .isPresent ()) {
        sessionValidator.check (vinnicaSession);
        addSessionToCache (myClassSession);
    }
    return myClassSession;
}
```

But the result is not a substitute. And the getCurrentSession method is executed. I can not understand why this is so

Comment: Mocking an object is useless  if the mocked object is not used by the method under test. Show all the relevant code.

Comment: You mock the dependencies of a class under test and not the class itself. Here you are trying to test & mock `ServiceManager` class. Doesn't make any sense.